# A simple example of tidy evaluation for formulas

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

I am trying to grasp tidy evaluation from `rlang`. As a short example I would like to add a column of predictions to a data frame. This is implemented in `modelr`, but I wanted to pass the formula directly so I could practice some tidy evaluation.

I have the following function

```
add_predictions <- function(data, model_exp){
  enquo_model_exp <- enquo(model_exp)
  fit <- data %>% as_tibble()  %>% !!enquo_model_exp
  data[[preds]] <- stats::predict(fit, data)
}
```

The above function has the following steps

1. `enquo` the formula
2. fit a model with the data and unqoute the formula with `!!`
3. predict using the fitted model on the data

an example of this functions usage would be something like the
following.

```
cars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  add_predictions(lm(speed ~ dist, data = .))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing formulas as arguments is straightforward and I wouldn't recommend
tidy evaluation for that. I would do this as follows (using just a bit of tidyeval
for the new column name):

```
library(tidyverse)

add_predictions <- function(.data, formula,
                            .fun = lm, col = pred) {
  col <- enquo(col)
  col <- quo_name(col)
  mod <- .fun(formula = formula, data = .data)
  mutate(.data, !! col := predict(mod))
}

cars %>% 
  add_predictions(speed ~ dist, col = speed_pred) 

#    speed dist speed_pred
# 1      4    2   8.615041
# 2      4   10   9.939581
# 3      7    4   8.946176
# 4      7   22  11.926392
# 5      8   16  10.932987
# 6      9   10   9.939581
# 7     10   18  11.264122
# 8     10   26  12.588663
# 9     10   34  13.913203
# 10    11   17  11.098554
# ...
```

Now I understand that you want to use tidy evaluation as an exercise. 
Using your desired function signature:

```
add_predictions_2 <- function(.data, model_exp, col = pred) {
  col <- enquo(col)
  col <- quo_name(col)
  model_exp <- enquo(model_exp)
  mod <- rlang::eval_tidy(model_exp, data = list(. = .data))
  mutate(.data, !! col := predict(mod))
}

cars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  add_predictions_2(lm(speed ~ dist, data = .))

# # A tibble: 50 x 3
#    speed  dist  pred
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     4     2  8.62
#  2     4    10  9.94
#  3     7     4  8.95
#  4     7    22 11.9 
#  5     8    16 10.9 
#  6     9    10  9.94
#  7    10    18 11.3 
#  8    10    26 12.6 
#  9    10    34 13.9 
# 10    11    17 11.1 
# # ... with 40 more rows
```

Comment: The `:=` function is new to me. Could you explain how it works? Also, how do you know what should have a `.` in front of it. If `.`s represent variables which are passed to the function then wouldn't all the variables be dotted (`.data`, `.model_exp`, `.col`)?

Comment: Aurele can probably explain more fully, but `.data` is a special pronoun in `rlang`. There is no general `.` operator. And `:=` is a workaround for the fact that you can't unquote with `!!` in front of an `=` sign in R, so you just put in `:=` when you want to do that.

Comment: @CalumYou is right. dot-prefixed names in R have no special meaning or properties (except that they're "hidden" by default when you do `ls()` for instance). Prefixing with `.` is an arbitrary choice, made by imitation of what seems to be the norm in the tidyverse. `:=` is exactly what @CalumYou describes, and the rationale is presented here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html  , with more details there http://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html